# Python3- How should I create a function that can disable a nested function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newb here. I'm trying to create a function that can keep track of other functions. It needs to also disable a nested function silence() and continue to run the rest:

```
import dis
import inspect
import sys

def foo():
    global print
    print('Entering foo()...')  

    #unsilence (disable) this function
    def silence(*args):
        pass
    print = silence

    print('silence() has been disabled, congratulations!')

def solution():
    #you can only code here
    #use sys.settrace and inspect
    pass

def main():
    print('Start!')
    solution()
    foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it should output:

```
Start!
Entering foo()...
silence() has been disabled, congratulations!
```

I have no idea what to put inside the solution() function to disable silence(). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or an online coding challenge?

Comment: `print = silence` followed by `print('blah')`is just going to call `silence('blah')`

Comment: What does "disable" mean here? What should happen when `foo` is called? Turning `silence` into `None` or something else not callable isn't all that hard, but it would just mean that the `print(…)` at the end raises a `TypeError: NoneType not callable` or something. Turning into a do-nothing callable wouldn't have any effect, because that's what it already is. Turning it into something that you can assign to `print` without affecting the binding of `print`, on the other hand, is impossible; there is no such thing. And I can't think of anything else that "disable a function" could mean.

Comment: It looks like there could be an interesting problem here, but you need to explain it better. If this _is_ an assignment or challenge or something, maybe quote directly from the requirements instead of trying to put them in your own words.

Comment: @abarnert. Why wouldn't you be able to set `silence` to point to `builtins.print` if you can set it to `None`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure, you could do that, but in what sense is that "disabling" the `silence` function?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions in the comments are pretty clear, but the definition of "disable" is not. I really shouldn't be posting an answer to this, but I learned a lot just now and couldn't resist.

The first step is to set a trace function with `sys.settrace` this will allow you to inspect and intercept the instructions that are being executed. Once you have that, you can detect an assignment to the global `print` function and intercept it. In the example below, I've done it by line number. This is obviously not very robust, but should get you started:

```
def solution():
    #you can only code here
    myprint = print
    def mytrace(frame, event, arg):
        if frame.f_lineno == 14:
            frame.f_globals['print'] = myprint
        return mytrace
    sys.settrace(mytrace)
```

A better solution might be to just check

```
if frame.f_globals['print'] is not myprint:
```

A more convoluted alternative might be to intercept the line starting with `def silence`, and replace the code block of the function with the code block of a function that reads

```
print(*args)  # being careful to refer to the original print and not the replacement
```

I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.